# WCF authentication performance?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, asp.net-identity

In my WCF service implementation I used username/password for authentication, with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and with the following codes.

```
    public class IdentityValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Validate "+userName);
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        using (var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context))
        using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore))
        {
            var user = userManager.Find(userName, password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var msg = String.Format("Unknown Username {0} or incorrect password {1}", userName, password);
                Trace.TraceWarning(msg);
                throw new FaultException(msg);//the client actually will receive MessageSecurityException. But if I throw MessageSecurityException, the runtime will give FaultException to client without clear message.
            }


        }
        Debug.WriteLine("End validate " + userName);
    }
}
```

and the config is like

```
        <behavior name="authBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="IdentityValidator,Security" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="RoleAuthorizationManager,Security"></serviceAuthorization>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
```

The functionality of authentication is so far so good. And the client is typically a Windows desktop app that will persist the user name and password all the time.

I understand the WCF authentication is per message. That means each call will run though some SQL queries against the database that stores the user name and password hash. So far in my low traffic test, the performance is good enough, say the authentication could be done within 1 second.

However, under heavy traffic, I wonder if it is a good idea to cache the result of querying the database, for example, before running userManager.Find, check if the userName and password pair had been authenticated in MemoryCache with 10 minutes expiry.

Is this something micro performance optimization? or in your experiences, did you need to be concerned by the performance of authentication of WCF services, built-in or custom?